# How to write "deriving instance" declaration?

Tags: haskell, deriving

I'm trying to store a crypto hash as a field in a record type, but the compiler complains:

```
HashTest.hs:13:1: error:
• No instance for (Data (Digest MD5))
    arising from the second field of ‘MyRecord’ (type ‘Digest MD5’)
  Possible fix:
    use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
      so you can specify the instance context yourself
• When deriving the instance for (Data MyRecord)
   |
13 |                          } deriving (Show, Eq, Data, Generic)
   |                                                ^^^^
```

Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable    #-}

module Playpen.HashTest.HashTest where

import Data.Generics (Data, Typeable)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

import Crypto.Hash

data MyRecord = MyRecord { idx :: Int
                         , sig :: Digest MD5
                         } deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)
```

If I write a standalone "deriving instance" clause as follows ...

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving    #-}

module Playpen.HashTest.HashTest where

import Data.Generics (Data, Typeable)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

import Crypto.Hash

data MyRecord = MyRecord { idx :: Int
                         , sig :: Digest MD5
                         } deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

deriving instance Data MyRecord
```

... then the error becomes

```
HashTest.hs:16:1: error:
    • No instance for (Data (Digest MD5)) arising from a use of ‘k’
    • In the expression: ((z MyRecord `k` a1) `k` a2)
      In an equation for ‘Data.Data.gfoldl’:
          Data.Data.gfoldl k z (MyRecord a1 a2)
            = ((z MyRecord `k` a1) `k` a2)
      When typechecking the code for ‘Data.Data.gfoldl’
        in a derived instance for ‘Data MyRecord’:
        To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
      In the instance declaration for ‘Data MyRecord’
   |
16 | deriving instance Data MyRecord
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

HashTest.hs:16:1: error:
    • No instance for (Data (Digest MD5)) arising from a use of ‘k’
    • In the expression: k (k (z MyRecord))
      In an equation for ‘Data.Data.gunfold’:
          Data.Data.gunfold k z _ = k (k (z MyRecord))
      When typechecking the code for ‘Data.Data.gunfold’
        in a derived instance for ‘Data MyRecord’:
        To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
      In the instance declaration for ‘Data MyRecord’
   |
16 | deriving instance Data MyRecord
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can anyone help me to understand this error and how to fix it?

Comment: What will go wrong if you do not have `Data` or `Generic` instances for this type?

Comment: @DanielWagner as it tuns out, nothing.  MyRecord is the payload of a Data.Tree.  Based on examples of using that type, I had assumed that the payload had to be an instance of Data and Generic.  But, having removed those from the declaration of MyRecord, my application still compiles.

Answer (score 2):

One choice would be to skip the `Data` and `Generic` instances until they're definitely needed; then at that point learn enough about `Data` and `Generic` to implement them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

To derive a `Data` instance for your type, all types it contains should also have that instance.

Make `Digest MD5` an instance of `Data` too.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on how to implement `Data` instance without having `Digest` constructors visible?